# Keep calculator from opening a new window every time I press the "Calculator" button on the keyboard?

Tags: 11.10, calculator

**Currently what happens:**

I press Calculator button on my keyboard, and calculator pops up. No problem there!
Next, after my calculation, I click back to the window where I'm inputting the calculation, and when I press the calculator button again, a **NEW** window opens in the calculator program.

**What I want to happen:**

When I click the calculator button, it switches back to the calculator program if it's already open, else, open calculator program.  I don't want it to open a new window every time I try to change back to my recent calculation.

It's not a big deal, obviously, just a slight annoyance to me so far.  Is there a setting, or some terminal command I can run, or **anything** I can do to change it?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Why not use Alt+Shift+Tab

Comment: Good point, but I think maybe you mean Alt+Tab ?  Alt+Shift+Tab doesn't do anything on my machine....

Comment: on my machine Alt+Shift+Tab lets me shift between windows(im on 10.10). **maybe** for you it might be Alt+Tab

Answer (score 8):

The tiny script below will do what you want. You need to install `wmctrl` for it to work:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

After you've installed `wmctrl`, paste the text below into a file and call it whatever you want. I called mine *calc-activate.sh*.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#This script switches focus to gnome-calculator if it is running.
#If it is not running, it will run gnome-calculator.

if [ "$(wmctrl -l | grep Calculator)" != "" ]; then
    wmctrl -a "Calculator"
else
    gnome-calculator &
fi
```

After saving, the text file, make it executable either by right clicking and going to the permissions tab and checking off the *Execute*  boxes, or do it from the terminal with the `chmod` command).

Now you can set your multimedia keys:

- For Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier, go to: *System* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*
- For 12.04 and later, hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, type "shortcut" then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Now find the "Launch calculator" shortcut, click on it and hit backspace to disable it.
- Now you can add a new custom shortcut. Point the command to the full path of the script you just saved. Click on the new command and press the calculator button to assign it. Voila!

Please note: Since `wmctrl` looks for a program titled "Calculator" the above script snippet might not work with other languages. To fix, change Calculator so it matches the window title of `gnome-calculator`.

Danish example:

```bash
if [ "$(wmctrl -l | grep Lommeregner)" != "" ]; then
    wmctrl -a "Lommeregner"
else
    gnome-calculator &
fi
```

Comment: Great tip - still using this and works over 8 years later! I've made a tiny alteration - it was opening this browser window as Calculator was in the title. The following code stops that from happening:

`wmctrl -F -a Calculator; if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  gnome-calculator &;
fi
`

Comment: I suggested an update to the answer based on @wayfarer_boy's useful improvement

Comment: The script is awesome, but it's not being called for my calculator button (Fn+F4).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "Microsoft keyboard and mouse" program, uninstall it and install intellitype and intellimouse from Microsoft.
I use a microsoft 5000 keyboard and mouse and recently installed MS K&M.   Every time I pressed the calculator button it would open a new calculator.  Intellitype will allow calculator to re-focus on the one that is open.